# Is $a+a$ contained in the cyclic submodule over $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I want to clarify one concept. Let $M$ be a left-module over a ring $R$.

The cyclic submodule generated by $a\in M$ is $\langle a\rangle=\{ca\mid c\in R\}$. So is $a+a$ always in such submodule? From the definition, I can't see the reason.

Comment: If $\langle a \rangle  = \{ca, c\in R\}$ it means that there is $c$ such that $ca = a$, because by definition $\langle a \rangle$ is the smallest submodule that contains $a$. Thus $a+a = ca+ ca = (c+c)a$ (note that usually, "ring" refers to unital ring, therefore you may take $c=1$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, suppose the ring $R$ has a unit element $1$. Then the ring contains $2=1+1$, $3=2+1=1+1+1$ and so on. Thus $2a = (1+1)a=a+a\in\langle a\rangle$.

The definition of $R$-module usually requires $R$ to have a unit element. If not, you can always argue that a submodule must be closed under addition.

Comment: How if not $R$ doesn't have unity?

Comment: @Eric If the ring doesn't have identity, then your definition of $\langle a\rangle $ is wrong. It would have to be $\{na+ca\mid n\in\mathbb Z,c\in R\}$ to contain $a$.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks for the helpful information!!